# How perform database transactions in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I recently have been working in Visual Studio 2015 and I have to perform database transactions for my project. In the internet documentation that I've watched, them always use the System.Transaction namespace, in fact, I've used it before in Visual Studio 2012, but when I try to include it in my project I always get an error because this namespace doesn't exist.

Someone knows if I have to install some aditional component to include it in my project?

Comment: Did you add the reference to System.Transactions? And the relative Imports of System.Transactions?

Comment: Yes I did, but the Visual Studio 2015 IDE says me that the namespace doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

From my csharp experience, the transaction object is in the same namespace as the database connection object. You just need to do

```
var trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
```

then attach that transaction to each command that you want to include in the transaction before executing. Finally you call Commit() on the transaction (or Rollback() if you want to cancel).

See here for details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm working with a DbContext's instance that encapsulates the database connection, with It I worked in a previous project in visual studio 2012. In that project I only included a "Using" clause creating a  TransactionScope instance and I achieved to define the transaction, but in visual studio 2015 it is not working because I can't import the System.Transactions namespace